# Замещение старых данных в файле java

Tags: java

Проблема в следующем: данные в файле постоянно перезаписываются, а необходимо, чтобы они помещались вслед за старыми.

```
public void createProduct() {
    List<String> data = new ArrayList<>();
    setProductData();
    data.add(getIdentify());
    data.add(getProductName());
    data.add(getDate());
    try {
        Files.write(productPath,data);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    System.out.println("Дейтсвие успешно выполнено!\n");
}
```

Comment: Files.write(productPath, data, StandardOpenOption.APPEND);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно добавить опцию записи файла `StandardOpenOption.APPEND`

```
Files.write(productPath, data, StandardOpenOption.APPEND)
```